# jQuery if each has value then

Tags: jquery

How would I be able to write it so that if the span says Newbie then its one color and if the span says Club Staff then it has another color?

```
<span class="usertitle">Newbie</span>
<span class="usertitle">Club Staff</span>​
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you running into trouble? (Why did you name your son Kiefer? ;-) )

Comment: If you have control over the output, why don't you just make classes in your CSS for each value and you add the according class to a value? I think it is much better than trying to hack this with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**js case sensitive**:

```
$('span.usertitle:contains('Newbie')').addClass('newbieColor');
$('span.usertitle:contains('Club Staff')').addClass('clubStaffColor');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/bjkcj/)

**js case insensitive**:

```
$('span.usertitle').html(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if(text === 'newbie') {
        $(this).addClass('newbieColor');
    } else if(text === 'club staff') {
        $(this).addClass('clubStaffColor');
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/bjkcj/1/)

**css**:

```
.newbieColor {
    color: yellow;
}

.clubStaffColor {
    color: red
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try `:contains` selector:

```
$(".usertitle:contains('Newbie')")
```

or `each` method:

```
$(".usertitle").each(function(){
 if ( $.trim($(this).text()) == 'Newbie' ) {
     // $(this).css('color', 'blue')
 }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.usertitle').each(function() {
        if ($(this).html() == "Newbie") $(this).css("color","blue");
        else if ($(this).html() == "Club Staff") $(this).css("color", "red");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TgFfm/

Comment: Your fiddle only works because your markup is not quite the same as the OP's. (The OP's markup will have slightly different text nodes.)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to work from the content:

```
$(".usertitle").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var color;
    switch ($.trim($this.text())) {
        case "Newbie":
            color = "green"; // For instance
            break;
        case "Club Staff":
            color = "red";   // For instance
            break;
    }
    if (color) {
        $this.css("color", color);
    }
});
```

<s>Note the use of `$.trim`, which is oddly missing from the other answers here, since your markup may include whitespace on either side of the words in your spans.</s> Your updated markup in the edit will not. But I'd still use `$.trim` because it doesn't cost much and makes things less delicate.

(Or, of course, rather than `css`, use `addClass` so you can control the presentation via stylesheets.)

But I'd really try to find a way to work from something other than the content if you possibly can.

Or more compactly and declaratively:

```
var colors = {
    "Newbie":     "green",
    "Club Staff": "red"
};

$(".usertitle").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var color = colors[$.trim($this.text())];
    if (color) {
        $this.css("color", color);
    }
});
```

Again, or rather than `css`, use a `classes` table rather than a `colors` table and use `addClass`, so you can control the presentation via stylesheets, e.g.:

```
var classes = {
    "Newbie":     "newbie",
    "Club Staff": "club-staff"
};

$(".usertitle").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var cls = classes[$.trim($this.text())];
    if (cls) {
        $this.addClass(cls);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use CSS classes and `addClass()`

```
$('.usertitle').each(function(){
  var t = $(this),
      text = $.trim(t.text())
  t.addClass(
    text === 'Newbie' && 'green' ||
    text === 'Club Staff' && 'red' ||
    !text && 'default'
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.usertitle').each(function(){
  var text = $.trim($(this).text());
   if(text == "Newbie"){
     // one color
   }
   else if( text == "Club Staff"){
     // another color
   }
});
```

Comment: 1. `text` is a function, not a property. 2. ***Very*** delicate (see my note on the earlier answer from Jorge)

Comment: And now you're repeatedly calling `$()` and `text()`. Why do it over and over again? Unnecessary work. And again: 2. ***Very*** delicate (see my note on the earlier answer by Jorge).

Comment: Jorge has deleted his answer: Your code won't work with the posted markup, because the strings don't *quite* match.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for suggestions !. can you please explain why strings don't match?

Comment: @ Mohammed: With the OP's original markup (now edited), there would be spaces on either side of the text in the spans. With the OP's edit, that's no longer true. Your use of `$.trim` in a recent edit fixes that so it would work with either markup.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) page says that .contains() can Check if an element is inside another element. Text and comment nodes are not supported.  how can we compare text then ?

Comment: @ Mohammed: As I said, your edit fixes it. I might use `else` in there or some other mechanism, and certainly you need to limit your initial selector rather a bit, but other than that you're largely there now. But `$.contains` isn't what another answer here uses, the other answer uses the [`:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) (quite different).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder still need to learn a lot...:)...  thanks anyway!